# Hot questions (network)

Tags: feature-request, questions

Would it be possible to get an API method for the stackexchange [hot questions list](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)?

Something like an official version of this: http://stackexchange.com/genuwine

Second to this would be knowing how to calculate the list but that would require a lot of API calls.

Third to this would be having vectorized site parameters so that multiple sites can be queried at once and the results combined?

Comment: The easiest of those options might be another global method like `/questions` (without a `site` parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Whilst an API method would be so much more helpful, and easy to use, the mobile apps use the URL http://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile. You can send a GET request to that URL and parse it easily because it's in JSON format.

It's an array of objects, eg:

```
[  
   {  
      "site":"codegolf.stackexchange.com",
      "question_id":91182,
      "title":"This isn\u0027t rocket science",
      "display_score":217.78446240641657,
      "icon_url":"http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "creation_date":1472191989,
      "answer_count":23,
      "user_name":"Helka Homba",
      "tags":[  
         "code-golf",
         "string",
         "ascii-art"
      ]
   },
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
]
```

See [Accessing the Hot Network Questions via the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280365/260841) for more details (the source of this answer).